# Change NSNumberFormatter's negative format from (xxx.xx) to -xxx.xx

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, number-formatting, negative-number

I want to change my NSNumberformatter from displaying negative numbers with parenthesis around them to putting the minus sign in front (or whatever the localized standard is).

I would assume I could do this with setNegativeFormat:

but reading Apple's oh so thorough docs I am left scratching my head:

---

**setNegativeFormat:**

Sets the format the receiver uses to display negative values.

```
- (void)setNegativeFormat:(NSString *)aFormat
```

**Parameters**
aFormat
A string that specifies the format for negative values.

**Availability**
Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.

**See Also**
– negativeFormat

**Declared In**
NSNumberFormatter.h

---

what are my options for aFormat?!?  C'mon Doc Writers, would a link here kill you?

edit: for what it's worth here's the declaration:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

It's important for me to retain the localized currency symbol & decimal places whatever they may be. So [currencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-#,##0.00"] probably won't work as currency is missing and 2 decimals can't be assumed for all currencies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you take a look at the "Format Strings" section in the [Data Formatting Programming Guide For Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW5):

> The format string uses the format patterns from the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Number_Format_Patterns) (this reference is to version tr35-6; formatters for Mac OS X v10.4 use version [tr35-4](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Number_Format_Patterns)).

**Edit:**

If you want to set a format string based on currencies, you can use the `¤` character, for example:

```
[formatter setFormat:@"¤#,##0.00"];
```

This will add the currency symbol for the current localization in place of the `¤` character.

Therefore, applying the same concept to the negative format string:

```
[formatter setFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];
```

This will also apply the currency symbol in place of the `¤` for the current localization.

Comment: so when I add: "[currencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-#,##0.00"];" after I set the formatter to NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle I lose the currency symbol. I could force in a "$" but that defeats the purpose of the CurrencyStyle in other Locales. Isn't there some way to just say something like setNegativeFormat:MinusSignFormat or something?!?

Comment: Before you could edit I was able to find that "¤" character thanks to your link. So I'll give you the gold star!  Thanks!

Comment: Note that this messes up any localized currency formats. I ended up using the positive format and adding the minus sign to it like so: [formatter setNegativeFormat:[@"- " stringByAppendingString:[self.numberFormatter positiveFormat]]];

Comment: How would I display a negative/positive number based on locale formatting without the currency symbol ?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so the answer that I got working is:

```
[currencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];
```

the key is this whatzit? character "¤". No idea what it's called? anyone? but it represents the localized currency in these format strings...

Comment: I'm not sure that it has a name, but it's Unicode symbol 00A4

Comment: Its names, according to UnicodeChecker, are “currency sign” and “other currency symbol”.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is looking for a format NSString.  [Look here for format string details](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/df100103.html).

If you want the negative of `12,345.67` to display as `-12,345.67`, then I believe the correct NSString value is `@"-#,##0.00"`

I also noted the following sentence in the document linked above:

> If you don’t specify a format for
>   negative values, the format specified
>   for positive values is used, preceded
>   by a minus sign (-).

EDIT:
Update for 10.4 and after:  [Here is a PDF describing behavior in 10.4 and after](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FConceptual%2FDataFormatting%2FDataFormatting.pdf&ei=DUQ6SobbL4P-tQPayOW2Bw&usg=AFQjCNHfP63dcTyukYI7lhesOmjHb3YKmQ&sig2=9qtunPbNMS7aorDStXszVg)

And, as linked from that document, here is the [data on the required format for 10.4 and after](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Number_Format_Patterns).

From this document, it appears the correct string may be: `@"-#,##0.##"`

Comment: I think that link is for the old style NSNumberFormatter (10.0 - 10.3). I'm using the 10.4+ version (Cocoa-Touch). I thought that "-#,##0.00" style was abandoned due to localization issues?!?

Comment: "If you don’t specify a format for negative values, the format specified for positive values is used, preceded by a minus sign (-)." Might be true for 10.0-10.3 but i'm getting parenthesis "(...)"

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers given assume that the currency is to two decimal places and also uses commas as thousand separators. Obviously there are a number of currencies that don't conform to this standard, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark, so I use the following technique

```
    NSString * formattedBalance = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:balance];
    if([formattedBalance rangeOfString:@"("].location != NSNotFound ) {
        formattedBalance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",[[formattedBalance stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"" ]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"" ]];
    }
```